# MongoDB $centerSphere vs Redis geospatial

Tags: mongodb, redis, geospatial, geohashing

I want to show nearby places on the map for a given user.
I can do so either by query MongoDB like this:

```
db.places.find( {
  loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ -88, 30 ], 10/3963.2 ] } }
} )
```

and either by query a Reids geospatial set like this:

```
georadius key longitude latitude 100 m
```

Any pros and cons?

Comment: It really depends of which stack you are already using in your application, do you use any of them?

Comment: Yes I am using MongoDB and I can achieve this using the $geoWithin, but I wonder if it will be wise to implement this over Redis.. But I think you are right and its better going on with mongo as it now.